# getSuggestions textext in jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-textext

I have problem with `getSuggestions` plugin in UI dialog. Code:

```
input.textext({
    plugins: 'tags autocomplete',
    tags: {items: tagItems},
    ext: {
        core: {
            serializeData: function (data) {
                return data.join(',');
            }
        },
        tags: {
            onPreInvalidate: function (event) {
            }
        }
    }
}).bind('getSuggestions',function (e, data) {
        console.log('get');
    }).bind('anyKeyUp',function (event) {
        console.log('keyup');
    }).bind('focusout', function (event) {
        console.log('focus');
    });
```

Other binds working fine. What can it be caused? This code working if is not in dialog UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find issue:

https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/jquery-textext/issues/92

Works fine for me.